# How to create a shrink animation in uinavigationbar?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I use this code in objective c to make a fade in fadeout animation when the user scrolls up or down the uitableview. Is there any way to make a nice animation like shrinking the navigationbar slowly while the user scrolls to top slowly? The more he scrolls to the top the more the navigationbar should shrink.

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 
    CGFloat scrollPos = self.tableView.contentOffset.y ;

       if(scrollPos >= _currentOffset ){
           //hide navbar and fadeout
           
          [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
              self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0f;
           }];
       } else {
           //Slide it up incrementally and fadein, etc.
           [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50 animations:^{
               
           [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
               self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 1.0f;
           }];
       }
}
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    scrollView = self.tableView;
     _currentOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset.y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot customize the size of `UINavigationBar` on your own. You can only hide/appear it. Apple does not allow you to do that.

You can use `UIView` instead! Just hide your `UINavigationBar` and put the same frame of `UIView`. Since `UIView` is highly customizable, you can do whatever you want.

Comment: So i can not shrink the navigationbar but can i move it slowly out of screen and then bring it back to its place on scroll down?

Comment: @stefanosn No You cannot change `UINavigationBar`'s default animation.

Comment: what if i just change the tableviewframe.origin.y by minus 1 it should on viewdidscroll? without using animation...